# Can we deploy Web Site scoped Feature (Scope="Web") to Site Collection(Scope="Site")?

Tags: feature

Can we deploy Web Site scoped Feature (Scope="Web") to Site Collection(Scope="Site")? I think applying force command in powershell creates unwanted trouble. what is actual business case scenario of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK no. If you deploy a *web scoped* feature to 'site collection', it will be actually deployed to root web of a site collection. It will still be accessible through **Site features** link in *Site settings*, and not through **Site collection features** link.

Force flag has nothing to do with the scope.